# Making Google Docs into its own application on Mac

Tags: google-docs, google-chrome, osx

I've been trying to figure this out all afternoon...

My dream is that I want to be able to open Google Docs on my Mac as if it's an application.  Chrome's setting's has a built-in "Add to Applications" option, but this opens Google Doc as a tab in my normal Chrome browser.

I want Docs to open in its own window.  Better yet, I want it to open up with all the browser menus (navigation bar, bookmarks bar, "tabs" bar) invisible, to that it looks like a standard application.

Basically I'm looking to be able to use Docs without all the distractions of the browser.

Comment: Check [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com).

Comment: See [here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/fluid-turns-websites-into-apps-on-your-mac/)

Comment: Check out [Applicationize](https://applicationize.me).